# Python floating-point precision format specifier

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, precision

Let's say I have some 32-bit numbers and some 64-bit numbers:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> w = np.float32(2.4)
>>> x = np.float32(4.555555555555555)
>>> y = np.float64(2.4)
>>> z = np.float64(4.555555555555555)
```

I can print them out with `%f` but it has extra, unneeded decimals:

```
>>> '%f %f %f %f' % (w, x, y, z)
'2.400000 4.555555 2.400000 4.555556'
```

I can use `%g` but it seems to have a small default precision:

```
>>> '%g %g %g %g' % (w, x, y, z)
'2.4 4.55556 2.4 4.55556'
```

I was thinking I should use something like `.7` for 32-bit values and `.15` for 64-bit values:

```
>>> '%.7g %.7g %.15g %.15g' % (w, x, y, z)
'2.4 4.555555 2.4 4.55555555555556'
```

This seems to work reasonably well, but the precision number is also used up for numbers in front of the decimal place too, e.g. 34567.375768.

In summary, what is the correct way to serialize floating-point values to text such that it preserves appropriate precision for 32-bit and 64-bit values but doesn't use any unnecessary space?

**Update**:

Examples of what I *think* the output should be:

```
number                float32     float64
5                     5           5
0.1                   0.1         0.1
2.4                   2.4         2.4
4.555555555555555     4.5555553   4.5555555555555554
12345678.92345678635  12345679.0  12345678.923456786
```

What I get with .7/.16. This actually looks okay:

```
>>> v32 = np.array([5, 0.1, 2.4, 4.555555555555555, 12345678.92345678635], dtype=np.float32)
>>> v64 = np.array([5, 0.1, 2.4, 4.555555555555555, 12345678.92345678635], dtype=np.float64)
>>> ('%.7g ' * len(v32)) % tuple(v32)
'5 0.1 2.4 4.555555 1.234568e+07 '
>>> ('%.16g ' * len(v64)) % tuple(v64)
'5 0.1 2.4 4.555555555555555 12345678.92345679 '
```

Comment: For me it is not really clear which output you desire. Could you provide us with the specific output you want to have?

Comment: I'd simply use strip('0') to remove trailing zeros.

Comment: What is wrong with `"%.3f" % z` -> '4.556', `"%.3f" % q` -> '2131234.556'?

Comment: How is '%.16g' (I think .16 is correct) not exactly what you need? Always 16 signficiant figures... You could also just use '%r' (representation) which is probably the same result. "used up in front" sounds like you have some misconception about floating points?

Comment: The precision number being also used up for numbers in front of the decimal point is a feature. Since those digits also take up room, they are just as important as those after the decimal place. When one speaks of *significant* 15 or 7 digits, the digit count always refers to the total number of digits.

Comment: updated with examples of what I want the output to be

Comment: @seberg I think I might have been mistaken then about the proper way to represent the floating point value. Is .7/.16 correct then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try to use the [`np.finfo`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html) function to get the precision corresponding to your float

```
finfo32 = np.finfo(np.float32)
finfo64 = np.finfo(np.float64)

finfo32.resolution = 1e-6
finfo64.resolution = 1e-15
```

Now that you know how many decimals you want, say, 6, just use a `rstrip("0")` to get rid of the unnecessary 0s:

```
print ("%.6f" % your_float).strip("0")
```

If you're leaning towards `%g`, perhaps you may want to use a dynamic format such as:

```
>>> strf = lambda v: ("%%.%ig" % max(np.ceil(np.log10(v)), 7)) % v
>>> strf(123.456789)
'123.45679'
>>> strf(123456789.12345)
'123456789'
```

Comment: updated question, I think ``%g`` does actually do what I want it to

Comment: @jterrace: I'm not sure about that, check the last entry of `v32` with '%.7g'.

Comment: Seems strange that it's ``1.234568e+07`` instead of ``1.234569e+07``?

Comment: That's what ``%g`` does.. it uses ``%e`` if it's more efficient. I'm actually okay with scientific notation

Comment: Yeah, the example was what I *thought* the answer should be, but I guess %g is okay. Still not sure what precision I should be using to make sure I don't lose precision

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish. However, this might help. You wrote

*This seems to work reasonably well, but the precision number is also used up for numbers in front of the decimal place too, e.g. 34567.375768.*

You can use `%f` instead of `g`. From the Python [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> The precision is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be
>   displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted
>   with 'f' and 'F', or before and after the decimal point for a floating
>   point value formatted with 'g' or 'G'.

```
>>> z = np.float64(4.555555555555555)
>>> "%.3f" % z
'4.556'
>>> q = np.float64(2131234.555555555555555)
>>> "%.3f" % q
'2131234.556'
>>>
```

Comment: Then change the '3' to another value. I still don't entirely get what you want.